# Moving Business layer from one place to another and getting all DLL references

Tags: asp.net

I have a NET (EPiServer) solution with many projects. In my Presentation project I have a folder (Business) that contains all Business Layer classes that needs to interact with the Presentation Layer, which is why I have placed this Business Layer inside the Presentation Layer. 
However I would like to move this Business folder inside its own project. That is I want to create a new class project which I will name "projectName.Business".

However the files in the Business-folder contains many dll references. I would like to know whether there is an easy way to get all the dll references with me when moving the business-folder to its own project, so that I dont have to reinstall all DLL's and their correct version in the new Business project.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use Nuget for those DLLs?

Comment: Yes nuget has been used for all packages. I'm aware that I can use nuget to reinstall all packages, however there is 50+ packages, hence I'm looking for a way to do it all in some simple steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Productivity Power Tools Visual Studio addon (for [VS 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace), [2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)) to copy-paste references from Presentation to Business Layer project.
Also Resharper has a Move command to move classes/folders to another location,  which will also update usings in all dependencies.  It will not copy project references, but just adjust namespaces and usings.

Comment: the reshaprer does not install the dependencies, you have to manually figure out which one you need and then go through them one by one and add them using e.g. nuget